# Multiple XAML layouts in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

App I am trying to create in WPF/C# has quite a few buttons in a layout with a "TV screen" type panel above (its actually an FMS emulator for commercial aircraft). Many of the buttons change the layout, which are numerous TEXTBOXs on the tv screen.  My question is: is there a provision to encapsulate the layouts in different classes/files and load them into the "tv screen" at the selection of the various buttons? In other words, user hits the Flight Plan button and the layout of the 355x355 box (screen) above loads the XAML "flight_plan" layout/file/class. Each layout has different TEXTBOX sizes & locations and there are in excess of 30 different "pages", which would make encapsulating them desirable.

I am very new to WPF and c#, but have written win apps in c++ all the way back to Turbo C & OWL. I also may be trying to do something that isn't possible due to working lately in Android/Java and am confusing capabilities.

Thanks in advance.

***Edit***
Thanks to @adityaswami89 and everyone else who got me on the right track, I have found the solution.  I added the pages via a new "WPF Page" in VS2012.  Then changed the "screen" to a navigation frame and it was truly simple from there. Below is the simple project I created to test it.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
       NavRad navrad = new NavRad();
       FPlan fplan = new FPlan();

       public MainWindow() {..}

       private void Frame_Navigated_1(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e) {..}

       private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           Screen_Frame.Navigate(fplan);
       }

       private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           Screen_Frame.Navigate(navrad);
       }
```

Comment: Just use some `UserControls`. Otherwise restyle the `TabControl` to have Buttons in the headers. There are thousands of ways to achieve this. What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything just yet but will definitely look at UserControls.  I just started doing research tonight and didn't know where to begin. I already have about 1000 lines written and figured there had to be an easier & more logical way to do it.

Comment: you have 1000 lines written for what? WPF doesn't require that much code for anything, it's very very different from what you might be used to in c++ or else. Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: It requires a lot of nested IF statements to parse whether the user types in an alphanumeric waypoint/airport information or numbers like speed or altitudes. An input like "SEA/+25" needs to be validated via a database waypoint and then created 25 miles past SEA based on the current route of flight and the current location of the "aircraft".  That is very different than typing /25 which would be translated as flight level 250. And both depend on which side of the display the data is inserted. I will try to post a picture later today. Thanks

Comment: @DaveS. I did a similar project a few years ago. We end up using Finite State Machines for parsing that kind of input. See more at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: @RandolfR-F. Thanks again for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: @HighCore. Sorry, my reputation is still to low to post a picture, but I'm working on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the concept of Frames for the intended functionality , if that can be an option you are looking.

You can refer the below link for the same.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx#Frame_in_Standalone_Applications

Comment: This solution actually did it for mew.  I have edited my post above to include the code.  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad it worked :) Keep coding. I also blog at adityaswami89.wordpress.com .

Answer (score 2):

You can abstract the different UI Layout Sets within different User Controls and load them according your UI logic. One way to do this is using an MVVM framework, for example, Caliburn Micro makes this a pretty simple task as doing:

> ActivateItem(UILayoutViewModel);

And this call can be called from any method.

See more of Caliburn Screens and Composition at [official source](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition).

Comment: The examples at the site you linked are very similar to what I need.